# Pandas - Add Columns to a DataFrame Based in Dict from one of the Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the `pandas.DataFrame` below:

[image]

One of the columns from the Dataframe, `pontos`, holds a dict for each of the rows.

What I want to do is add one column to the DataFrame for each key from this dict. So the new columns would be, in this example: `rodada`, `mes`, etc, and for each row, these columns would be populated with the respective value from the dict.

So far I've tried the following for one of the keys:

```
df_times["rodada"] = [df_times["pontos"].get('rodada') for d in df_times["pontos"]]
```

However, as a result I'm getting a new column `rodada` filled with `None` values:

[image]

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a slight change in your comprehension to extract that data.

It should be:

> df_times["rodada"] = [d.get('rodada') for d in
>   df_times["pontos"]]

You want the values of the dictionary key 'rodada' to be the basis of your new column. So you iterate over those dictionary entries in the loop- in other words, d,  and then extract the value by key to make the new column.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a new dataframe and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) it to the current one like:

#### Code:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(df.pontos))], axis=1)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', dict(col1='1', col2='2')],
    ['B', dict(col1='3', col2='4')],
], columns=['X', 'D'])

print(df)

df2 = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(list(df.D))], axis=1)
print(df2)
```

#### Results:

```
   X                           D
0  A  {'col2': '2', 'col1': '1'}
1  B  {'col2': '4', 'col1': '3'}

   X                           D col1 col2
0  A  {'col2': '2', 'col1': '1'}    1    2
1  B  {'col2': '4', 'col1': '3'}    3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use join and pandas apply function:

```
df=df.join(df['pontos'].apply(pd.Series))
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22926444)